# How to build task 'assets:precompile'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, production, asset-pipeline

I'm getting that error on my production server, and can't figure out why. It happens when running this command:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

I'm using Rails 3.1.0.rc6

Comment: It means there is no task `assets:precompile` for your application. May be a missing gem or something.

Comment: which gem would that be? I had just run "gem install rails --pre" and then "rails new ..."

Comment: I am not sure, haven't used 3.1 yet.

Comment: Are you actually using bundler in production? Is your production server on Heroku?

Comment: @Jack Chu I'm just trying to compile the assets. No, not heroku.

Comment: Are you sure you have sprockets installed? Also, you dont need RAILS_ENV=production, that specific task is always run as production by default.

Comment: In my case I just had to add the gem 'sass-rails' in the gemfile. Maybe it can help someone.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This is most likely due your `config/application.rb` not requiring `rails/all` (the default), but some custom requires.

To resolve this, add the following to `config/application.rb`:

```
require 'sprockets/railtie'
```

Comment: This is common issue for Mongoid users that delete rails/all config

Comment: thank god, someone spotted this, I confirm the said phenomenon

Comment: bingo. I am indeed a Mongoid user.

Comment: So .. I have this problem, but this wasn't the problem.  requiring sprockets/railtie was not missing from my config.

Comment: That problem was solved but I got a new error in terminal as:
Sprockets::ArgumentError: manifest requires output filename

Comment: Note that creating a Rails 5 API-only project with ```$ rails new my_api --api``` generates an application.rb file with that specific line commented out.

Answer (score 8):

I was running this command -- out of sheer habit -- in the root of an API-only app, which, of course, has no assets.

Comment: Oh. thank you this saved me. My app was also an API-only application.

Comment: Add me to the list..

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old post but I thought it might help someone (probably my future self) if I added this to the answers.

#### add to Capfile (or deploy.rb)

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```

#### add this to application.rb

```
require 'sprockets/railtie'
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. but on rails 2. i've added these lines but it didn't help (and not to application.rb but to enviroment.rb)

Comment: This fixed it for me on Thin + Rails 3.2 with Mongodb.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I think that it might be because you aren't requiring the asset gems in production. By default rails expects that you are pre-compiling your assets in production. Change this in config/application.rb:

Comment out this line:

> Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))

And uncomment this line:

> Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)

Comment: I'm not a mongoid user like the currently accepted answer mentions in the comments. In my case I had a seperate environment just to precompile assets and the error went away once I added the new environment to the list mentioned in this answer.

Comment: I had an extremely old app (2008), that doesn't even have sprockets, so this is the answer I needed. Cap defaults to expecting to precompile the asset pipeline, but since there is no asset pipeline it fails.

Answer (score 1):

That's strange. You could always try adding

```
load "sprockets/assets.rake"
```

to your Rakefile. It should be included by the actionpack railtie.

My Rakefile contains:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
Qnm::Application.load_tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
Add `require "sprockets/railtie"` in `applications.rb`.
And create an empty manifest file `app/assets/config/manifest.js`