# How can I reset my asset pipeline in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, asset-pipeline

Such a strange problem, but I deployed to production, and it won't update with my new CSS changes because of a caching issue.

I tried this :

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

But that returns :

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'assets:precompile'
```

Ah, so I must be missing the sprockets in my application.rb perhaps. I tried everything on this link : [How to build task 'assets:precompile'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205964/dont-know-how-to-build-task-assetsprecompile) . And every solution caused a load error for not finding the items that it pointed out.

What should I do?

Rails. 3.0.5

Comment: Rails 3.0.5 doesn't include the asset pipeline (at least not out of the box)

Comment: Ah.. how would you reset the assets cache then?

Comment: Depends on what you have - if it's just plain old css files then there is no cache (other than the fact that browsers will cache previously fetched files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try clearing your browser cache.

this blog post was informative for me: http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/02/untangling-the-rails-asset-pipeline-part-1-caches-and-compass/